# Get the SQL for a Rails 3 Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I really like how in Rails 3 you can ask a scope for its SQL like this:

```
User.admins.to_sql
```

Is there any way to do the same thing with a `has_many` relation?:

```
User.first.jobs.to_sql
```

I've tried `User.first.jobs.public_methods.grep /sql/` and other tricks, but I haven't turned up anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`User.first.jobs.scoped.to_sql`